# Convert a given xml to another xml using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an input xml like
XML Input:

```
    <parent>
        <child>
            <child2 name="Action">Change</child2>
            <child1 name="Change">

                <child2 name="Dest_Author">Author1</child2>

                <child2 name="Book1">BookID1</child2>
                <child2 name="Type1">General</child2>
                <child2 name="Pages1">100</child2>

                <child2 name="Book2">BookID2</child2>
                <child2 name="Type2">Cooking</child2>
                <child2 name="Pages2">200</child2>

                <child2 name="Orig_Author">Author2</child2>

                <child2 name="Book1">BookID3</child2>
                <child2 name="Type1">General</child2>
                <child2 name="Pages1">150</child2>

                <child2 name="Book2">BookID4</child2>
                <child2 name="Type2">Cooking</child2>
                <child2 name="Pages2">120</child2>

            </child1>
        </child>
    </parent>
```

I want to convert it to the following xml using xslt transformation
Expected XML output:

```
    <list>
        <author id="Author1">
            <book>
                <id>BookID1</id>
                <type>General</type>
                <pages>100</pages>
            </book>
            <book>
                <id>BookID1</id>
                <type>Cooking</type>
                <pages>200</pages>
            </book>
        </author>    
        <author id="Author2">
            <book>
                <id>BookID1</id>
                <type>General</type>
                <pages>150</pages>
            </book>
            <book>
                <id>BookID1</id>
                <type>Cooking</type>
                <pages>120</pages>
            </book>
        </author>
    </list>
```

I tried converting it using xslt but was not able to do so.
My xslt look like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="parent">
        <list>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </list>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="child">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="child1">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="./@name='Change'">
                <author>
                    <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of
                        select="./child2[@name='Dest_Author']" /></xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:apply-templates />
                </author>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="child2">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains(@name,'Orig_Author')">
                <!-- I thought of changing the below code(line no 36-38) as
                </author>
                <author>
                    <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></xsl:attribute>
                but if do this it throws error "The element type "xsl:when" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</xsl:when>"."
            -->
                <author>
                    <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></xsl:attribute>
                </author>
            </xsl:when>

            <xsl:when test="contains(@name,'Book')">
                <book>
                    <id>
                        <xsl:value-of select="text()" />
                    </id>
                    <xsl:variable name="next"
                        select="./following-sibling::node()[@name!=''][1]"></xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="contains($next/@name,'Type')">
                            <type>
                                <xsl:value-of select="$next" />
                            </type>
                            <pages>
                                <xsl:value-of select="$next/following-sibling::node()[@name!=''][1]" />
                            </pages>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="contains($next/@name,'Pages')">
                            <pages>
                                <xsl:value-of select="$next" />
                            </pages>
                        </xsl:when>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </book>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>    
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XSLT output:

```
<list>
    <author id="Author1">
        <book>
            <id>BookID1</id>
            <type>General</type>
            <pages>100</pages>
        </book>
        <book>
            <id>BookID2</id>
            <type>Cooking</type>
            <pages>200</pages>
        </book>
        <author id="Author2"/>
        <book>
            <id>BookID3</id>
            <type>General</type>
            <pages>150</pages>
        </book>
        <book>
            <id>BookID4</id>
            <type>Cooking</type>
            <pages>120</pages>
        </book>
    </author>
</list>
```

Can someone help me and tell what changes the xslt code requires to get the correct output

Comment: What did your XSLT look like? Rather than give you the code, it may be that your code wasn't far off.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive

Comment: Do you _really_ want all the books in your required output to have the same id `BookID1` or is that a typo?

Comment: The output is exactly what I want.Anyways, the below code works fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would treat this as a grouping problem.  You want to attach each `child2` whose name does *not* include `_Author` to its nearest preceding sibling whose name *does* include `_Author`, and generate one `author` element per group.  Then within the groups you want to attach each non-`Book` element to its nearest preceding `Book` and generate one `book` element per group.

XSLT has the concept of *keys* which can be used to group elements.  I would define two keys, first

```
<xsl:key name="booksByAuthor" match="child2[starts-with(@name, 'Book')]"
   use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::child2[contains(@name, '_Author')][1])" />
```

which takes each `Book` (i.e. `child2[@name = 'Book1' or @name='Book2' or ....]`) and assigns it a grouping key based on the identity (`generate-id`) of the nearest preceding author.  A second key

```
<xsl:key name="bookDetails"
   match="child2[not(contains(@name, '_Author') or starts-with(@name, 'Book'))]"
   use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::child2[starts-with(@name, 'Book')][1])" />
```

groups all the "detail" elements (those that are not either `Something_Author` or `BookN`) by their nearest preceding Book.  These keys give you the hierarchical structure, and let you code the rest of the stylesheet as a normal system of template matching.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:key name="booksByAuthor" match="child2[starts-with(@name, 'Book')]"
       use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::child2[contains(@name, '_Author')][1])" />

    <xsl:key name="bookDetails"
       match="child2[not(contains(@name, '_Author') or starts-with(@name, 'Book'))]"
       use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::child2[starts-with(@name, 'Book')][1])" />

    <xsl:template match="/parent">
        <list>
            <!-- process all the authors -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select=".//child2[contains(@name, '_Author')]" />
        </list>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="child2[contains(@name, '_Author')]">
        <!-- for each author, create an author element -->
        <author id="{.}">
            <!-- and process this author's books -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('booksByAuthor', generate-id())" />
        </author>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="child2[starts-with(@name, 'Book')]">
        <!-- for each book, create a book element -->
        <book>
            <id><xsl:value-of select="." /></id>
            <!-- and process this book's details -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('bookDetails', generate-id())" />
        </book>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="child2[starts-with(@name, 'Type')]">
        <type><xsl:value-of select="." /></type>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="child2[starts-with(@name, 'Pages')]">
        <pages><xsl:value-of select="." /></pages>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you had other child types such as `Publisher1`, `Publisher2`, ... then you would just add additional templates along the same lines as the `Type` and `Pages` ones.